# Buggy screenshot file name

Tags: gnome-screenshot

I using Ubuntu 14.04 with Turkish language. My problem is screenshot file-naming.
When I press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, screenshot's file name buggy.

[image: SS naming problem]

File name is supposed to be like this:

```
Ekran görüntüsü 2014-07-17 15:11:40.png
```

That's what happens:

```
2014-07-17 15:11:40.png Ekran görüntüsü
```

What is the solution for this bug? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File a bug with the translator team.

Excerpt from `/usr/share/locale-langpack/tr/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-screenshot.mo`:

```
msgid "Screenshot from %s.%s" 
msgstr "%s.%s Ekran görüntüsü"
```

should be:

```
msgid "Screenshot from %s.%s" 
msgstr "%s ekran görüntüsü.%s"
```

Extension `png` goes into the second `%s`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @aquaherd is the correct one. It is a bug and should be corrected on the package level.

However, if you want to correct your setup right away, do the following:

1. Install `poedit`:

   ```
   sudo apt install poedit
   ```
2. Backup the existing file:

   ```
   cd /usr/share/locale-langpack/tr/LC_MESSAGES
   sudo cp gnome-screenshot.mo gnome-screenshot-backup.mo
   ```
3. Download a recent `.po` file with Turkish translations. I found one here, modified today: https://l10n.gnome.org/vertimus/gnome-screenshot/master/po/tr. It already contains the correction suggested in @aquaherd's answer.
4. Open the downloaded file with `poedit`, and "compile" the file to `/usr/share/locale-langpack/tr/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-screenshot.mo`. A `.po` file is a human-readable text file. A `.mo`file is just a compressed, binary format of the `.po` file.

The next time you use the screenshot utility, it will use the correct filename format.